# Data Not inserted in Database php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, api, mysqli

Can't insert data into DB . When i remove user_id then data is inserted. Please check below my code and help me.

```
function adddata($data) {
    global $db;
    if (is_array($data)) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `pay` (id, payment, status, itemid, time, user_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?');

        $userid = 2;
        $stmt->bind_param(
             'sdssss',
            $data['txn_id'],
            $data['payment_amount'],
            $data['payment_status'],
            $data['item_number'],
            date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            $userid
        );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        return $db->insert_id;
        }
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: Think there is a missing `)` in `VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?');`

Comment: This stands to be a typo-based issue for more than just the missing bracket. The "id" column, is that an string based column or integer?

Comment: sir this is a string column of my id.

Comment: Is your `id` value always the same? Because if it's a primary key then you wouldn't insert.

Comment: yes got it,  thanks nigel Ren. bracket missing in my query. having also one issue can you please solve ? want to pass $_SESSION[userid]; in to my $userid variable. when i hardcode value in to $userid variable then query run successfully. but when pass $_SESSION[userid] query not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's subtle, but your SQL string is missing a closing bracket:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `pay` (...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
```

Where the `VALUES` list was not properly closed.

A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so mistakes aren't easily ignored. This should show up as a SQL error in your logs.

Comment: having also one issue can you please solve ? want to pass $_SESSION[userid]; in to my $userid variable. when i hardcode value in to $userid variable then query run successfully. but when pass $_SESSION[userid] query not execute

Comment: "Will not execute" is not sufficiently detailed. If you can be more specific, like the exact error text you're getting, it's worth opening this up as a new question where that problem can be addressed.